# Unexpected Behavior of Math.Floor(double) and Math.Ceiling(double)

Tags: c#, floating-point

This question is about the threshold at which `Math.Floor(double)` and `Math.Ceiling(double)` decide to give you the previous or next integer value.  I was disturbed to find that the threshold seems to have nothing to do with `Double.Epsilon`, which is the smallest value that can be represented with a double.  For example:

```
double x = 3.0;
Console.WriteLine( Math.Floor( x - Double.Epsilon ) );  // expected 2, got 3
Console.WriteLine( Math.Ceiling( x + Double.Epsilon) ); // expected 4, got 3
```

Even multiplying `Double.Epsilon` by a fair bit didn't do the trick:

```
Console.WriteLine( Math.Floor( x - Double.Epsilon*1000 ) );  // expected 2, got 3
Console.WriteLine( Math.Ceiling( x + Double.Epsilon*1000) ); // expected 4, got 3
```

With some experimentation, I was able to determine that the threshold is somewhere around 2.2E-16, which is very small, but VASTLY bigger than `Double.Epsilon`.

The reason this question came up is that I was trying to calculate the number of digits in a number with the formula `var digits = Math.Floor( Math.Log( n, 10 ) ) + 1`.  This formula doesn't work for `n=1000` (which I stumbled on completely by accident) because `Math.Log( 1000, 10 )` returns a number that's 4.44E-16 off its actual value.  (I later found that the built-in `Math.Log10(double)` provides much more accurate results.)

Shouldn't the threshold should be tied to `Double.Epsilon` or, if not, shouldn't the threshold be documented (I couldn't find any mention of this in the official MSDN documentation)?

Comment: Is it possible it has something to do with the ability to store such numbers in IEEE form. I wonder what Compare of 3.0 & 3.0 - Double.Epsilon would get.

Comment: @Rich: they should compare equal.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Double.Epsilon for equality, greater than, less than, less than or equal to, greater than or equal to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411392/double-epsilon-for-equality-greater-than-less-than-less-than-or-equal-to-gre)

Comment: No surprises there, 3.0 is also vastly larger than 0.0. They might look like just 3 apart, but that's a difference of more than half of the representable positive numbers (half of those are between 0 and 1).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Shouldn't the threshold should be tied to Double.Epsilon

No.

The representable doubles are not uniformly distributed over the real numbers. Close to zero there are many representable values. But the further from zero you get, the further apart representable doubles are. For *very* large numbers even adding 1 to a double will not give you a new value.

Therefore the threshold you are looking for depends on how large your number is. It is not a constant.

Answer (score 11):

[The value of `Double.Epsilon` is 4.94065645841247e-324](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.epsilon.aspx).  Adding or subtracting this value to 3 results in 3, due to the way floating-point works.

A `double` has 53 bits of mantissa, so the smallest value you can add that will have any impact will be approximately 2^53 time smaller than your variable.  So something around 1e-16 sounds about right (order of magnitude).

So to answer your question: there is no "threshold"; `floor` and `ceil` simply act on their argument in exactly the way you would expect.

Comment: So basically, there aren't enough significant digits in a double to denote the difference between between 3 and 3 - Double.Epsilon. By this note, the original posters threshold would be different for, say 11 or 111 because of the additional digits of significance needed vs 3.

Comment: @Rich: Indeed, but that "threshold" applies to basic floating-point arithmetic, not to `floor` and `ceil`.

Comment: I would have expected `Double.Epsilon` to be 2.220446049250313e-16.

Comment: @dan04: Why?  It's the smallest non-zero value.

Comment: Because that's what [machine epsilon is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon) is.

Comment: @dan04: Machine epsilon is relative error.  `Double.Epsilon` doesn't claim to be machine epsilon (it explicitly says so in the docs).

Answer (score 3):

This is going to be hand-waving rather than references to specifications, but I hope my "intuitive explanation" suits you well.

Epsilon represents the smallest magnitude that can be represented, that is different from zero. Considering the mantissa *and* exponent of a double, that's going to be extremely tiny -- think 10^-324. There's over three hundred zeros between the decimal point and the first non-zero digit.

However, a `Double` represents roughly 14-15 digits of precision. That still leaves 310 digits of zeros between Epsilon and and *integers*.

`Double`s are fixed to a certain bit length. If you really want arbitrary precision calculations, you should use an arbitrary-precision library instead. And be prepared for it to be significantly slower -- representing all 325 digits that would be necessary to store a number such as `2+epsilon` will require roughly 75 times more storage per number. That storage isn't free and calculating with it certainly cannot go at full CPU speed.

Comment: Nice answer. I'd rephrase, that subtraction or addition of numbers with magnitudes at the edge of precision and lesser in floating point arithmetics may no effect, which should be expected result of operation. So it is not "unexpected"