# Is there a FLT_EPSILON defined in the .NET framework?

Tags: c#, .net, floating-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Double.Epsilon for equality, greater than, less than, less than or equal to, greater than or equal to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411392/double-epsilon-for-equality-greater-than-less-than-less-than-or-equal-to-gre)

I recently discovered that `FLT_EPSILON` as defined in `<cfloat>` is not at all the same as `Single.Epsilon` as defined in the .NET Framework.

- `FLT_EPSILON` is defined as the smallest such that 1.0 + epsilon != 1.0.
- `Single.Epsilon` is defined as the smallest possible number greater than zero.

Is there a `<cfloat>`-style epsilon defined somewhere in the .NET Framework? Or if I need to define my own, should that be defined identically in .NET as the value I see in `<cfloat>`?

Comment: The linked question doesn't seem to have an answer for the specific cfloat constant I'm looking for, though the other question is certainly related.

Comment: There is no such constant in .NET, the linked question shows the alternative.  There's otherwise nothing from stopping you to declare it yourself.  The math is the same.

Comment: The other question and answers are very focused on equality comparisons, which I'm not necessarily here. I'm basically porting code which used epsilon to avoid divide-by-zero => infinite.

Comment: Yes, that is what an epsilon is good for.  Using one to avoid Infinity in a division is a very long shot.  Arbitrarily: 1E160 / 1E-160 generates Infinity, 1E148 / 1E-160 does not.  High odds that you are doing it wrong, FLT_EPSILON isn't going to be helpful.

Comment: @HansPassant I think in our case our units worked out conveniently enough to use FLT_EPSILON to avoid infinity. Your point is valid though.

Comment: `FLT_EPSILON` is **not** defined as “the smallest such that 1.0 + epsilon != 1.0”. It is defined as the difference between 1.0f and its successor. http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/05/09/FLT_EPSILON

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By all accounts this is not defined anywhere in the .NET Framework.

If you need the identical constant you can define it as `float Epsilon = 1.192092896e-07F;`.

For a larger discussion about alternatives and usage see: [Double.Epsilon for equality, greater than, less than, less than or equal to, greater than or equal to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411392/double-epsilon-for-equality).