# Double.Epsilon Value

Tags: c#

I feel like this should be easy to find somewhere online but I'm having a hard time.

Does anyone know what the c# value is for `Double.Epsilon`? I'm looking for the exact numerical value.

Comment: How did you research? I get `4.94065645841247E-324` in LINQPad

Comment: "1.7976931348623157E+308" this quite big number :) I don't think it's smallest double :D

Comment: MSDN link: [`Double.Epsilon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.epsilon.aspx)

Comment: "4,94065645841247E-324"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is its declaration:

```
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public const double Epsilon = 4.94065645841247E-324;
```

Answer (score 3):

No, this certainly is not correct.

First: The value of `Double.Epsilon` can easily be found out by either a small program or by reading the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.epsilon.aspx):

```
4.94065645841247E-324
```

Second: Don't confuse this value with [Machine Epsilon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon) which is usually used in comparisons between two double values. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18081222/572644) for more details on "Machine Epsilon".

Answer (score 3):

None of these answers is the exact numerical value. The exact value is a power of 2, namely 2^-1074, as this is how IEEE floating point numbers are actually stored in modern computers.  All the other answers given are decimal approximations. If you assign that decimal approximation to a `double`, then it will round off to 2^-1074, so internally, the register or memory location will receive the true "Epsilon" value. So, using the decimal constant to initial a storage location to the minimum floating point value works, but the decimal constant is still *not* the actual value of this minimum floating point value.

Explanation: The smallest positive value written in IEEE notation is

0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001B x 2^-1022.

(The B is for binary base)

That is a 1 shifted 52 bits to the right of the binary point, then shifted another 1022 bits for a total of 1074 bits. The leading sign bit is zero. Sign bit (1 bit) plus coefficient (52 bits) plus exponent (11 bits) give 64 bits of storage.

Note also this is a "denormalized" floating point value, because the exponent is -1022.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point and search for "1074".

ps. My calculator gives a more precise representation of the value of `Double.Epsilon` = 2^-1074 as 4.9406564584124654417656879286822e-324.

Answer (score 2):

[MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.epsilon.aspx):

> The value of this constant is 4.94065645841247e-324.