# Problem with float and int multiplication in C

Tags: c, types, floating-point, multiplication

I'm using the online compiler https://www.onlinegdb.com/ and in the following code when I multiply 2.1 with 100 the output becomes 209 instead of 210.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() 
{
    float x = 1.8;

    x = x + 0.3;

    int coefficient = 100;

    printf("x: %2f\n", x);

    uint16_t y = (uint16_t)(x * coefficient);

    printf("y: %d\n", y);

    return 0;
}
```

Where am I doing wrong? And what should I do to obtain 210?

I tried to all different type casts still doesn't work.

Comment: "I tried to all" A good scientist shows *all* of his work.

Comment: Casting floating point to integer rounds down. Use `round` function explicitly.

Comment: Floating point numbers are stored in a binary format.  1.8 and .3 are both repeating fractions in binary (1.11001100... and .0100110011..., respectively) and so lose precision being stored slightly less than the wanted decimal value.

Comment: Do the rounding first, then cast to uint16_t

Comment: `float x = 1.8;` gave you 1.7999999523162841796875.  And then adding 0.3 (which is really 0.300000011920928955078125) gave you 2.099999904632568359375.  And then multiplying that by 100, and throwing away the fraction, gave you 209.  Try `printf(%.20f\n", x);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following assumes the compiler uses IEEE-754 binary32 and binary64 for `float` and `double`, which is overwhelmingly common.

> `float x = 1.8;`

Since `1.8` is a `double` constant, the compiler converts 1.8 to the nearest `double` value, 1.8000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125. Then, to assign it to the `float` `x`, it converts that to the nearest `float` value, 1.7999999523162841796875.

> `x = x + 0.3;`

The compiler converts 0.3 to the nearest `double` value, 0.299999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875. Then it adds `x` and that value using `double` arithmetic, which produces 2.09999995231628400205181605997495353221893310546875.

Then, to assign that to `x`, it converts it to the nearest `float` value, 2.099999904632568359375.

> `uint16_t y = (uint16_t)(x * coefficient);`

Since `x` is `float` and `coefficient` is `int`, the compiler converts the `coefficient` to `float` and performs the multiplication using `float` arithmetic. This produces 209.9999847412109375.

Then the conversion to `uint16_t` truncates the number, producing 209.

One way to get 210 instead is to use `uint16_t y = lroundf(x * coefficient);`. (`lroundf` is declared in `<math.h>`.) However, to determine what the right way is, you should explain what these numbers are and why you are doing this arithmetic with them.

Answer (score 1):

Floating point numbers are not exact, when you add 1.8 + 0.3,
the FPU might generate a slightly different result from the expected 2.1 (by margin smaller then float Epsilon)
read more about floating-point numbers representation in wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon

what happens to you is:

1.8 + 0.3 = 209.09999999...
then you truncate it to int resulting in 209

you might find this question also relevant to you [Why float.Epsilon and not zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30216575/why-float-epsilon-and-not-zero) might be

Comment: Actually, floating point numbers can be perfectly exact — they're just not exact *in decimal*.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main() 
{
    float x = 1.8;

    x = x + 0.3;

    uint16_t coefficient = 100;

    printf("x: %2f\n", x);

    uint16_t y = round(x * coefficient);

    printf("y: %" PRIu16 "\n", y);

    return 0;
}
```