# Calculating the total amount of change given

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop

Hello I'm currently following the Computing with C# and the .NET Framework book and I'm having difficulty on one of the exercises which is

> Write a C# program to make change. Enter the cost of an item that is less than one dollar. Output
>   the coins given as change, using quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies. Use the fewest coins
>   possible. For example, if the item cost 17 cents, the change would be three quarters, one nickel,
>   and three pennies

Since I'm still trying to grasp c# programming the best method I came up with is using the while loop.

```
while(costOfItem >= 0.50)
            {
                costOfItem -= 0.50;
                fiftyPence++;
            }
```

I have these for each of the pences 20,10,5 etc.. 
I'm checking if the amount is greater than or equal to 50 pence, if so, i reduce 50 pence from the amount given by the user and add 1 to the fiftypence variable.

then it moves onto the next while loop, which I have for each pences. The problem is, somewhere along the line one of the loops takes away, lets say 20 pence, and the costOfItem becomes something like "0.1999999999999" then it never drops down to 0, which it should to get the correct amount of change.

Any help is appreciated, please don't suggest over complex procedures that I have yet covered.

Comment: What type of unit are you using for the money given?

Comment: what datatype are you using for `costOfItem`? Sounds like its `float`, if that's true, you should try `decimal` instead.

Comment: You need to use `decimal` to represent money.  Floating point types like `double` and `float` are not appropriate and will result in these sort of issues. See [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165761/decimal-vs-double-which-one-should-i-use-and-when).

Answer (score 5):

Never use `double` or `float` for money operations. Use `Decimal`.
For all other problems of calculation accuracy you have to use "Double Epsilon Comparison" like [Double.Epsilon for equality, greater than, less than, less than or equal to, greater than or equal to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411392/double-epsilon-for-equality-greater-than-less-than-less-than-or-equal-to-gre)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me you are using `float` or `double` as datatype for `costOfItem`.
`float` and `double` store their values in binary. But not all decimal values have an *exact* representation in binary. Therefore, a very close **approximation** is stored. This is why you get values like "0.1999999999999".

For **money calculations**, you should **always** use `decimal`, since they avoid those small inaccuracies.

You can read more about the difference in [Jon Skeets awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/618596/3107430) to [Difference between Decimal, Float and Double in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/618535/3107430)

Answer (score 0):

If you do the calculation in cents, you can use integers and then you don't get into floating point rounding problems

Comment: this is called Mill Representation and is based on the Mill Currency. All operations are based on integer. 1000 Mill = 1 Dollar.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the fast replies. The issue was that i used **double** instead of **decimal** the links provided have people explaining why it's wrong to do so in some cases. Using **double** should be avoided in arithmetic since apparently some float numbers do not have exact a binary representation, so instead of .23 it gives 0.2299999999999. Changing the variable to decimal fixed my issue