# Failing IF logic statement for doubles c#

Tags: c#, if-statement

I was attempting the hallenge/problem as below in HackerRank. (You don't have to sign in to view the problem, for those who don't wish to view it via the link I'll write a briefly about the problem statement).

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/time-conversion

Given a specified input (string) of date (02:34:50PM) in AM/PM format,  I had to convert it into military time (14:34:50). Midnight in Military is 00:00:00 and in AM/PM format is 12:00:00AM as for Afternoon in Milatary is 12:00:00 and in AM/PM format is 12:00:00PM.

Now the approach I used was checking the 2nd last value of the string since the input format was specified. B/c I only need to change the hours I only take the 0th and 1st index of string convert it into double using "GetNumericValue".

Now when I use the values of these doubles in my IF statement (in the PM if block) they fail if I check for "!=". I've given the code below. After using the debugger and seeing what happens it completely forgoes the IF statement containing the "!=". This happens if my input has "1" in its first index or has "2" in its 2nd index.

At first I was thinking that it might be an issue with the precision of double with such a small number, however, my code gives the right answer if the input "01:xx:xxPM". So I'm inclined to think its the logic of my IF statement, though I've stared at it for so long and I have no idea why it won't work. I gave the alternate piece of code I wrote that worked. I essentially did the same thing except I used "==" and an else statement (before I was using "!=" and an else statement)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HackerRank_Algorithms
{
    class Time_Conversion
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //Reading input Date in the format "02:34:50PM"
            string time = Console.ReadLine();
            //Creating a double array for storing the first digits that is the hours
            //used double since 'GetNumericValue' returns type double
            double[] timeIn24 = new double[2];
            //loop to convert the first two digits from string into double 
            for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++)
            {
                timeIn24[x] = char.GetNumericValue(time, x);
            }

            //Because I know the date will always be in a specified format I check at the place for
            //'P' or 'A' for AM or PM 
            //If PM then do this
            if (time[time.Length-2] == 'P')
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Time is PM");

                /********************************************
                //I tried doing this since but didn't work
                //timeIn24[1] = Convert.ToInt32(timeIn24[1]);
                //timeIn24[0] = Convert.ToInt32(timeIn24[0]);
                *********************************************/

                //Console.WriteLine("Before {0} timeIn24[0]", timeIn24[0]);
                //Console.WriteLine("Before {0} timeIn24[1]", timeIn24[1]);


                //PROBLEM OCCURRING HERE I check if its 12PM or not if it isn't then I do the follwoing
                if (timeIn24[1] != 2 && timeIn24[0] != 1)
                {
                    //add 2 to the unit of hours
                    timeIn24[1] = timeIn24[1] + 2;

                    //Console.WriteLine("After addition {0} timeIn24[0]", timeIn24[0]);

                    //if the sum i get is greater than 10 that is I'm getting a carry
                    if (timeIn24[1] > 9)
                    {
                        //I add one to the tenth of hours
                        timeIn24[0] = timeIn24[0] + 1;
                        //Modulus to get the last digit of unith hour
                        timeIn24[1] = timeIn24[1] % 10;
                    }
                    timeIn24[0] = timeIn24[0] + 1;
                    Console.Write("{0}{1}", timeIn24[0], timeIn24[1]);


                    //Console.WriteLine(timeIn24[0]);
                    //Console.WriteLine(timeIn24[1]);
                }
                else //if its 12PM then I do not do anything and I print it as is
                {
                    Console.Write("{0}{1}", timeIn24[0], timeIn24[1]);
                }

                /***********CODE THAT GAVE THE CORRECT SOLUTION******************/
                //if (timeIn24[1] == 2 && timeIn24[0] == 1)
                //{
                //    Console.Write("{0}{1}", timeIn24[0], timeIn24[1]);


                //    //timeIn24[0] = timeIn24[0] / 10; 
                //    //Console.WriteLine(timeIn24[0]);
                //    //Console.WriteLine(timeIn24[1]);
                //}
                //else
                //{
                //    timeIn24[1] = timeIn24[1] + 2;
                //    //Console.WriteLine("After addition {0} timeIn24[0]", timeIn24[0]);
                //    if (timeIn24[1] > 9)
                //    {
                //        timeIn24[0] = timeIn24[0] + 1;
                //        timeIn24[1] = timeIn24[1] % 10;
                //    }
                //    timeIn24[0] = timeIn24[0] + 1;
                //    Console.Write("{0}{1}", timeIn24[0], timeIn24[1]);
                //}
                /******************************************************************/

                //Here I simply start from the first colon and print the date as string till end
                int y = 2;
                while( y < time.Length-2)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0}", time[y]);
                    y++;
                }
            }
            else //if its AM
            {
                //if its 12AM that is Midnight
                if (timeIn24[0] == 1 && timeIn24[1] == 2)
                { //set both tenth and unit of hour to 0
                    timeIn24[0] = 0;
                    timeIn24[1] = 0;
                }
                //print the hours
                Console.Write("{0}{1}", timeIn24[0], timeIn24[1]);

                //again print from first colon + the remaining of string
                int x = 2;
                while ( x < time.Length-2)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0}", time[x]);
                    x++;
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to compare double values using epsilon and not just == or != or >= or <=, etc.. See: Comparing Floats and Doubles with Epsilon. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411392/double-epsilon-for-equality-greater-than-less-than-less-than-or-equal-to-gre  and http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/

Comment: I think you'll have more success working with .NET's build in `DateTime` type.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: There is a lot of long winded academic stuff going on.  Does the hacker program disallow built in functions?  There should be user validation like `TryParse`.  And you already have 24 hr format `date.ToString("HH:mm:ss")`.

Comment: No the hacker program doesn't disallow inbuilt functions. I wanted to try building my own logic because usually in my school setting they disallow the usage of inbuilt functions. So for purposes of learning I implemented my logic instead of using the inbuilt functionality. But yes agreed I'll definitely would have more success with the inbuilt functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is indeed with the `if` statement. Think about using `10:00:00AM` as your input. In this case, `timeIn24[1] != 2` will evaluate to `true` (since the second digit is 0, not 2), but the second part, `timeIn24[0] != 1`, will evaluate to `false` because the first digit is indeed 1. Since you're using `&&`, *both* sides need to evaluate to `true` in order to enter the `if` statement.

If you use `||` (or) instead of `&&` (and), the `if` statement should work correctly, because if *either* digit isn't equal to the right value, the code will enter the `if` block.

Of course, like others have noted, unless it's specifically prohibited by the challenge, it'd be much simpler to just use the built-in `DateTime` type.

Comment: Ah yes you're absolutely right. I simply did not see it until I saw it written in your answer. Thank you.