# How can I test if a point is in an ellipse?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, collision-detection

I am working on a Pygame project and there is water on the map. I want to slow down the player if player goes into water. **Area where water is has an elliptic shape.** I can slow down player if the shape was a rectangle but i don't want the non-water area to slow down the player. So how can i get the area where player is supposed to be slowed down? **How to control if character's coordinates are in the ellipse?**

Edit: I checked the link in the comments and it worked for me.

Comment: Did you try searching for any existing algorithms? I came across [this one](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-a-point-is-inside-outside-or-on-the-ellipse/) which solves your problem

Comment: I checked the link and implemented it in my code. Changed few things and it worked. I looked for it on google but i didn't encounter that site, my bad.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect if an ellipse intersects(collides with) a circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945337/how-to-detect-if-an-ellipse-intersectscollides-with-a-circle)

Comment: The pygame solution is to use a [Sprite](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) with a mask. In that case the "water" can have any shape. See [How can I made a collision mask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56043600/how-can-i-made-a-collision-mask/56045037#56045037)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The collision of an ellipse and a point can be reduced to the collision of a circle and a point by scaling the ellipse to appear as a circle and scaling the distance vector of the point to the center of the ellipse in the same way. Since the ellipses are axis-aligned in PyGame, this can easily be achieved by scaling one of the coordinates by the ratio of the [ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse) axis length.

Define the bounding rectangle ([`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html)) of the ellipse (`ellipse_rect`) and get the semi-axis (`a`, `b`):

```py
a = ellipse_rect.width // 2
b = ellipse_rect.height // 2
```

Compute the ratio of the semi-axis

```py
scale_y = a / b
```

Define an point (`test_x`, `test_y`) and calculate the vector of the point to the center of the ellipse (`cpt_x`, `cpt_y`). Scale the y-coordinate of the vector with the ratio of semi-x-axis and semi-y-axis:

```py
cpt_x, cpt_y = ellipse_rect.center
dx = test_x - cpt_x
dy = (test_y - cpt_y) * scale_y
```

The point lies in the ellipse if the square of the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) (`dx*dx + dy*dy`) is smaller than the square of the semi-x axis (`a*a`):

```py
collide = dx*dx + dy*dy <= a*a
```

See also [Collision and Intersection - Point and Ellipse](https://github.com/Rabbid76/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/blob/master/documentation/pygame/pygame_collision_and_intesection.md#point-and-ellipse)

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()

width, height = 400, 400
window = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

ellipse_rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 200, 100)
ellipse_rect.center = window.get_rect().center

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    a = ellipse_rect.width // 2
    b = ellipse_rect.height // 2
    scale_y = a / b
    cpt_x, cpt_y = ellipse_rect.center
    test_x, test_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    dx = test_x - cpt_x
    dy = (test_y - cpt_y) * scale_y
    collide = dx*dx + dy*dy <= a*a  
            
    window.fill(0)
    
    color = (127, 0, 0) if collide else (0, 127, 0)
    pygame.draw.ellipse(window, color, ellipse_rect)
    if collide:
        pygame.draw.ellipse(window, (255, 255, 255), ellipse_rect, 3)

    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Comment: i think i was my bad to not mark it as solved. I didn't knew how to do that since i didn't use stackoverflow that much at the time. 
My question came out to be more related to math than pygame but i really appreciate your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Simple code to check the points
let ellipse is the object and x,y be the player's location

```
Path = ellipse.get_path()
if [x,y ] in Path:
       print('Yes')
```

For Example

```
Path=np.array([[ 0.        , -1.        ],
   [ 0.2652031 , -1.        ],
   [ 0.51957987, -0.89463369],
   [ 0.70710678, -0.70710678],
   [ 0.89463369, -0.51957987],
   [ 1.        , -0.2652031 ],
   [ 1.        ,  0.        ],
   [ 1.        ,  0.2652031 ],
   [ 0.89463369,  0.51957987],
   [ 0.70710678,  0.70710678],
   [ 0.51957987,  0.89463369],
   [ 0.2652031 ,  1.        ],
   [ 0.        ,  1.        ],
   [-0.2652031 ,  1.        ],
   [-0.51957987,  0.89463369],
   [-0.70710678,  0.70710678],
   [-0.89463369,  0.51957987],
   [-1.        ,  0.2652031 ],
   [-1.        ,  0.        ],
   [-1.        , -0.2652031 ],
   [-0.89463369, -0.51957987],
   [-0.70710678, -0.70710678],
   [-0.51957987, -0.89463369],
   [-0.2652031 , -1.        ],
   [ 0.        , -1.        ],
   [ 0.        , -1.        ]])
```

be the path

```
if [ 0.89463369,  0.51957987] in Path:
   print('Yes')
```