# Ray-Sphere intersection

Tags: c++, opengl

Is there any Ray sphere interestion code in OpenGL. I really need to understand that program so I am looking for it but can't find it. This seems to be popular problem but I can only find the formula and basic principle not any example.
http://wiki.cgsociety.org/index.php/Ray_Sphere_Intersection

I have no idea how to go about it. This is what I got: http://www.sendspace.com/file/8gb6fj

Has anyone of you done it or know for some source where I can get the program ?

Comment: The formula's all you need... there's also a C++ example on that page.

Comment: This is a math question, unless you want to see a working solution with OpenGL visualization?

Comment: What's with the downvotes? Other libraries provide intersection tests, and he's asking for an example either way. This isn't a pure math question (and since when do we care about that)?

Comment: @David: the link he provides has a formula, a proof, and example code.

Comment: [See also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073336/circle-line-collision-detection)

Answer (score 39):

let:

- A(xA,yA,zA) and B(xB,yB,zB) be two different points on the line
- C(xC,yC,zC) be the center of the sphere
- r be the radius of the sphere

the cartesian equation of the sphere is:

- (x-xC)²+(y-yC)²+(z-zC)²=r²

let us write the parametric equation of the line (parameter d):

- x = xA + d*(xB-xA)
- y = yA + d*(yB-yA)
- z = zA + d*(zB-zA)

replacing in the sphere equation yields:

- (xA + d(xB-xA) - xC)²+(yA + d(yB-yA) - yC)²+(zA + d(zB-zA) - zC)²=r²

This is a quadratic equation in d, where the discrimant is:

- Delta=b²-4*a*c

with:

- a = (xB-xA)²+(yB-yA)²+(zB-zA)²
- b = 2*((xB-xA)(xA-xC)+(yB-yA)(yA-yC)+(zB-zA)(zA-zC))
- c = (xA-xC)²+(yA-yC)²+(zA-zC)²-r²

if Delta<0 then there is no intersection

if Delta==0 then there is a single intersection point (the line touches the sphere)
the unique solution is d=-b/2a (from there use the parametric equations to compute the coordinates of the intersection point)

if Delta>0 then there are a two intersection points
the solutions are d1=(-b-sqrt(Delta))/(2a) and d2=(-b+sqrt(Delta))/(2a) (from there use the parametric equations to compute the coordinates of the intersection points)

---

So what you have to do is:

- compute a, b, c, and then Delta using the formulas above
- depending on its value, compute d or (d1 and d2)
- compute the coordinates of the intersection points if there are any

Comment: What does "the ray of the sphere" mean exactly?

Comment: sorry I meant radius... edited!

Comment: Thanks for replies I will see what I can do. BTW I found this on internet but do not know how to use as it is java. I got netbeans does anyone know how I can run this program. It seems this is also some ray-sphere intersection program: http://www.pixelnerve.com/v/2009/02/08/ray-sphere-intersection/

Comment: damn, no newline in comment or code allowed:

since you only want to know weather ray hits, this can be simpyfied even more. this is my hlsl-code

    float intersectRaySphere(float4 rayOrigin, float4 rayDirection, float4 sphere) {
 float4 sphereCenter = sphere;
 sphereCenter.w = 1.0f;
 float4 dist = rayOrigin - sphereCenter;
 float B_half = dot(dist, rayDirection);
 float C = dot(dist, dist) - sphere.w;
 return B_half * B_half - C;
    }

the w component of vector4s are 1 on position coordinate, 0 on direction normal and squared radius of the sphere. result above zero means hit :D

Comment: It shows weird functionality if there are minus coordinates in A or B. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

OpenGL is a pure drawing API, i.e. the whole thing is designed to provide drawing tools. There is no scene management, geometry tools, etc. Those must be provided by other means.