# Collision detection between a line and a circle in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, canvas, line, collision-detection, geometry

I'm looking for a definitive answer, maybe a function cos I'm slow, that will determine if a line segment and circle have collided, in javascript (working with canvas)

A function like the one below that simply returns true if collided or false if not would be awesome. I might even donate a baby to you.

```
function isCollided(lineP1x, lineP1y, lineP2x, lineP2y, circlex, circley, radius) {

    ...
}
```

I've found plenty of formulas, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073336/circle-line-collision-detection), but they are over my head.

Comment: Well, even if you didn't follow the maths, there was code presented in the answer there, which should be useful to you.

Comment: This is the exact moment that your high school algebra will help you out in your life.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: I would have thought so, too. But I was confused on the first line: "float a = d.Dot( d )" :)

Comment: @Derek: Agree. Now I'm 30, balding and have nothing to show.

Comment: Facts: Circle formula: `(x−h)^2+(y−k)^2=r^2` Line formula: `y=a+bx` You can solve for these 2 formula, and if you can get an answer, then there is a collision.

Comment: But that's just it, `(x−h)^2+(y−k)^2=r^2` doesn't mean anything to me.

Comment: See my answer. Try to solve for `CD`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you will need some Math:

[image]
This is the basic concept if you don't know how to solve equations in general. I will leave the rest of the thinking to you. ;) Figuring out `CD`'s length isn't that hard.

If you are asking how, that's how:
[image]
Finding collisions in JavaScript is kind of complicated.

Comment: A really really appreciate the help you've given me so far. But "find angle ABE then subtract angle DBE" is really not easy for me. I'm not mathematically inclined which is why I thought I'd give stackoverflow ago.

Comment: Nice graphics man! @Jarrod: Subtracting the numbers shouldn't be the problem, so I guess your problem is with trigonometry/vectors? There's lot of info about that on the internet, I doubt that it would be sensible to summarize it specifically for this question.

Comment: (Or simply `Math.atan((m1 - m2)/(1 + m1*m2))`, where `m` is the slope)

Comment: Don't be surprised if you found the angle does not look right, since in JavaScript all angle is in radian instead of degree.

Comment: Thanks again. Could you maybe go step by step as to how to get point C. I've still working on the problem but think I can work out the circle part.

Comment: @Jarrod - You don't need to find the coordinates of point C. `CD/BD = sin(CBD)` Therefore `CD = sin(CBD)*BD`

Comment: THANKS! But how do you calculate the restitution/resolve the collision? I mean, setting new position and velocities of the circle?

Comment: @Murplyx - I don't know much about physics, but you can [calculate the exact point of collision](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lnobsoneki). Maybe this can help?

Answer (score 5):

I Spent about a day and a half to make it perfect.. Hope this helps.

```
function collisionCircleLine(circle,line){ // Both are objects

    var side1 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(circle.x - line.p1.x,2) + Math.pow(circle.y - line.p1.y,2)); // Thats the pythagoras theoram If I can spell it right

    var side2 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(circle.x - line.p2.x,2) + Math.pow(circle.y - line.p2.y,2));

    var base = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(line.p2.x - line.p1.x,2) + Math.pow(line.p2.y - line.p1.y,2));

    if(circle.radius > side1 || circle.radius > side2)
        return true;

    var angle1 = Math.atan2( line.p2.x - line.p1.x, line.p2.y - line.p1.y ) - Math.atan2( circle.x - line.p1.x, circle.y - line.p1.y ); // Some complicated Math

    var angle2 = Math.atan2( line.p1.x - line.p2.x, line.p1.y - line.p2.y ) - Math.atan2( circle.x - line.p2.x, circle.y - line.p2.y ); // Some complicated Math again

    if(angle1 > Math.PI / 2 || angle2 > Math.PI / 2) // Making sure if any angle is an obtuse one and Math.PI / 2 = 90 deg
        return false;


        // Now if none are true then

        var semiperimeter = (side1 + side2 + base) / 2;

        var areaOfTriangle = Math.sqrt( semiperimeter * (semiperimeter - side1) * (semiperimeter - side2) * (semiperimeter - base) ); // Heron's formula for the area

        var height = 2*areaOfTriangle/base;

        if( height < circle.radius )
            return true;
        else
            return false;

}
```

And that is how you do it..

Comment: *"And that is how you do it.."*? But this is how you do not answer. on a lighter note, add some context to support your code buddy. Plainly posting some code is not a good way of answering.

Comment: I don't know if this works or not but Math.atan2 requires y and then x input you got it reversed.

Answer (score 1):

Matt DesLauriers published a Javascript library for this problem at https://www.npmjs.com/package/line-circle-collision. The API is straightforward:

```
var circle = [5, 5],
    radius = 25,
    a = [5, 6],
    b = [10, 10]

var hit = collide(a, b, circle, radius)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function pointCircleCollide(point, circle, r) {
    if (r===0) return false
    var dx = circle[0] - point[0]
    var dy = circle[1] - point[1]
    return dx * dx + dy * dy <= r * r
}

var tmp = [0, 0]

function lineCircleCollide(a, b, circle, radius, nearest) {
    //check to see if start or end points lie within circle
    if (pointCircleCollide(a, circle, radius)) {
        if (nearest) {
            nearest[0] = a[0]
            nearest[1] = a[1]
        }
        return true
    } if (pointCircleCollide(b, circle, radius)) {
        if (nearest) {
            nearest[0] = b[0]
            nearest[1] = b[1]
        }
        return true
    }

    var x1 = a[0],
        y1 = a[1],
        x2 = b[0],
        y2 = b[1],
        cx = circle[0],
        cy = circle[1]

    //vector d
    var dx = x2 - x1
    var dy = y2 - y1

    //vector lc
    var lcx = cx - x1
    var lcy = cy - y1

    //project lc onto d, resulting in vector p
    var dLen2 = dx * dx + dy * dy //len2 of d
    var px = dx
    var py = dy
    if (dLen2 > 0) {
        var dp = (lcx * dx + lcy * dy) / dLen2
        px *= dp
        py *= dp
    }

    if (!nearest)
        nearest = tmp
    nearest[0] = x1 + px
    nearest[1] = y1 + py

    //len2 of p
    var pLen2 = px * px + py * py

    //check collision
    return pointCircleCollide(nearest, circle, radius)
            && pLen2 <= dLen2 && (px * dx + py * dy) >= 0
}

var circle = [5, 5],
    radius = 25,
    a = [5, 6],
    b = [10, 10]

var hit = lineCircleCollide(a, b, circle, radius)
```