# HTML5 Circle Prevent Drag Outside Canvas and prevent collision

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas, drag

I have HTML 5 circle drag and drop example,

http://jsfiddle.net/eGjak/503/

i want to follow things

1. prevent drag circles outside of the canvas
2. hide lines over the circles
3. prevent drag over another circle

i play with some codes but no luck there. can anyone please help me, by logic or some helpful resource

Comment: Hello, do you have a working example of your requirements? I'm really interested in how you implemented the collision prevention. I know how to detect collision but not how to prevent it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. This is an easy one. It's simply checking x doesn't leave the left or right side of the screen and y doesn't leave the top or bottom of the screen

   if (x>0 || x<(canvas.width - circle.width) 
       && y>0 || y<(canvas.height - circle.height)) {

   ```
   ...update...
   ```

   }
2. Here you need to do a line/circle collision check. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10957689/577306).
3. For this you need circle/circle collision detection. The below will return true if collided otherwise false:

   ```
   this.isIntersecting = function(c1center, c1radius, c2center, c2radius)
   {

       var dX = Math.pow(c1center.x - c2center.x, 2);
       var dY = Math.pow(c1center.y - c2center.y, 2);
       var r2 = Math.pow(c1radius.radius() + c2radius.radius(), 2);
       return (dX + dY <= r2);
   }
   ```

c1center and c2center are object with x, y properties (eg: `c1center = {x:0, y:0 }`)