# Finding circle-canvas intersections with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, geometry, intersection

I'm drawing a `circle` on a `canvas`. I would like to know, given radius and origin x/y of a `circle`, at what points the `circle` intersects (if at all) with the `canvas` edges.

This is a geometry question for sure, but that part seems too simple to post elsewhere. The JavaScript part is escaping me completely. I'm not even entirely sure how to begin.

The `canvas` will vary in size, but that's easy enough to access. The `circle` will be dynamic in size and position as well, but those variables are readily available. Any hints or nudges in the right direction are very welcome.

**PS**

I am using RaphaelJS to draw the shapes, if that helps. If anyone has a solution for canvas/modern browsers, I can backwards myself the rest.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401847/circle-rectangle-collision-detection-intersection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a javascript intersection library like http://www.kevlindev.com/gui/math/intersection/index.htm#Anchor-intersectCircleRectangl-46622

You would define the rectangle as defined by the canvas (likely 0, 0, width, height).

Comment: Thanks for this! I would like to be able to work it out without a library (since I'll only need the one functions) but this is a great starting place!

Comment: You can also think of the problem as doing a circle-line intersection test 4 times, for the 4 lines of the rectangle.

Comment: Yup! that much is working now... but I'm having trouble finding the resulting angle of the origin to the intersection point. Sigh... high school, you were so long ago!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957689/collision-detection-between-a-line-and-a-circle-in-javascript might help with that.