# HTML5 Canvas Collision between circle and rectangle

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Circle-Rectangle collision detection (intersection)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401847/circle-rectangle-collision-detection-intersection)
>   [Collision detection between a line and a circle in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957689/collision-detection-between-a-line-and-a-circle-in-javascript)

This is more pseudo than actual working code...

```
var dX = rectanlge.x - circle.x;
var dY = rectangle.y - circle.y;
var distance = Math.sqrt((dX*dX)+(dY*dY));
if(distance < circle.radius){
     //Collision
}
```

This is all I have so far to detect whether a circle and rectangle collide in a canvas animation. I am clearly going wrong, can some one point me in the right direction?

```
rectangles = [];    
var rectangle = function(x,y,width,height){
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
        };
```

Then I would loop through this array

Comment: How is your `rectangle` defined?

Comment: I have added that into my question

Comment: For starters, you have `rectanlge` instead of `rectangle`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find very nice algorithm there: http://www.migapro.com/circle-and-rotated-rectangle-collision-detection/