# java swing intersection line with circle point

Tags: java, swing, math, geometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Circle line collision detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073336/circle-line-collision-detection)

I have a problem. I need to find point A.
[image]

How can I do this best way?

Programming languale is Java.

Comment: Programming language doesn't matter. This is basic maths.

Comment: This is not a java-specific question, it is pure math.

Comment: Yes, but if anyone has a solution to this programming language, it can share it without any additional explanations.

Comment: Is this `do my homework` question?

Comment: No, it's my 'I want to finish my project' question.

Comment: why do you think that this is a mathematical problem? Perhaps, there is a method for determining the point of intersection of the line and circle, or another way to learn this point with the help of a programming language.

Comment: @Max I think this is a more specific case, i.e. where the line starts at the centre of the circle - so the correct solution is potentially much simpler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given:
a circle with center C=[x2,y2] and radius R
a line segment from C to B=[x1,y2]
calculate their intersection.

This is easy since one of the endpoints is the center of the circle. You have to walk the distance of R from C towards B. The distance guarantees you will end up on the circle and the direction guarantees you will end up on the ray C->B. You still need to check if the intersection lies on the segment.

Here is the pseudocode if you have a vector library

```
- offset = B-C
- if length_square(offset) < R^2 output "no intersection"
- offset_a = normalize(B-C) * R
- output C + offset_a
```

Without a library, the code is longer:

```
- off_x = x1-x2;
- off_y = y1-y2;

- ls = off_x*off_x + off_y*off_y
- if ls < R*R
-- return an empty array, meaning "no intersections"

- scale = R / sqrt(ls)
- res_x = off_x * scale + x2
- res_y = off_y * scale + y2
- return [[off_x, off_y]]
```