# What is the optimized design methodology for a directed entity?

Tags: design-patterns, game-physics

I mean I want to have some directed objects in my game, like a laser beam or a rocket facing somewhere.

How would you store these  objects for collisions? (consider them like a circular shape to make thing easier)

My hypothesis' are:

-Either store two coordinate vectors

-Or Store a coordinate vector and an angle

Each have their advantages and drawbacks:
-Storing more data would mean more load in memory
-Storing less data would mean more load in calculations

I just don't know which would lead to a more optimized way, which is more generally acceptable?

Thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience two coordinate vectors is better.

And if you query and need angle a lot you can store angle also.

Also from my experience, for games speed is more important than memory

> premature optimization is the root of all evil 
>   http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization

Comment: Thank you, I accept this answer! Can I ask for a bit more detailed explanation please?

Comment: lets take two basic examples i pick randomly. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line-line_intersection and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line. There are no mention of angles. Also another one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073336/circle-line-collision-detection