# Find point with vector projection

Tags: java, algorithm, math

[image: pic]

I am trying to work this out in java with LatLng point

I was looking at this post here [Circle line-segment collision detection algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073336/circle-line-collision-detection)

I have a method to find distance between 2 point. The instruction says

Project the vector AC onto AB. The projected vector, AD, gives the new point D.
If the distance between D and C is smaller than (or equal to) R we have an intersection.

I don't have knowledge about vector,  could anyone help me how to find point D here ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, if the co-ordinates of `A` are `(ax,ay)`, and similarly for `B, C, D`, then the length of line segment `CD` is `|(cy-ay)(bx-ax)-(cx-ax)(by-ay)|/sqrt((bx-ax)^2+(by-ay)^2)` - I'll write a proper answer with a proof if I have time later.  Or you could take it to math.stackexchange.com, where the experts in this kind of thing hang out.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, in the meantime, I will try implement that as well.

Comment: Problem still remain.  I am still looking for a way to find point D

Comment: D= A + AC*cos(angle). I think that angle is 30 degree => D = A + AC/2

Comment: I thought you just wanted to know whether the length of CD was more or less than R.  Why do you need to know the coordinates of D?

Comment: @ArnaldoIgnacioGasparVéjar - not only is there no reason to assume that the angle is 30 degrees, but also `cos(30 degrees)` is not `1/2`.

Comment: @David Wallace its another point in this calculation I need to know as well to use it in the future. Sorry for unclear question.  But I also stated to find point D in the question as well

Comment: True, you did.  OK, as I said, I will post an answer later if I have time.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need D point coordinates - let's vectors
**AB** = (B.X-A.X, B.Y-A.Y)
**AC** = (C.X-A.X, C.Y-A.Y)
then the simplest (I believe) form of projection of C to AB is:

**AD** = **AB** * (**AB**.dot.**AC**) / (**AB**.dot.**AB**);
In coordinates:

```
CF=((B.X-A.X)*(C.X-A.X)+(B.Y-A.Y)*(C.Y-A.Y))/((B.X-A.X)^2+(B.Y-A.Y)^2)
D.X=A.X+(B.X-A.X)*CF
D.Y=A.Y+(B.Y-A.Y)*CF
```

Distance CD, as David Wallace has already written, is
|**CD**| = |**AC** x **AB**|/|**AB**|   (x = cross product)

Comment: thanks, I will try to verify that, but it might take sometime to test it for me, therefore, answer vote will be slow

Comment: What is CF variable?

Comment: CF is dimensionless parameter in vector equation `AD = cf * AB`(it is proportional to cosine of angle CAB and AC length)

Answer (score 0):

Let's think of `A, B, C` and `D` as Vectors and let

`*` for 2 vectors be the scalar product, i.e. the result is the sum of the products of the corresponding coordinates of the operands, and

`|X|` be the length of vector x, i.e. the square root of the sum of the squared values of the coordiantes of `X`

First we find the plane `P` (for 2D space the plane is a line) ortogonal to `F = (B-A)`, that contains `C`:

This plane is described by the following equation (where `Z` is arbitrary point in the plane):

`F * Z = F * C`

The equation for the line `G` from `A` to `B` is (`t`in real numbers):

`F * t + A`

To intersect `P` and `G` you have to solve the following equation:

```
  (F * t + A) * F = F * C
t * |F|^2 + A * F = F * C
        t * |F|^2 = F * C - A * F
                t = (F * (C - A)) / (|F|^2)
                t = ((B - A) * (C - A)) / (|B-A|^2)
```

To get `D` insert `t` into `G`:

```
D = F * t + A
  = (B-A) * t + A
```

In a 2D space, you get

```
ca1 = C1-A1
ca2 = C2-A2
ba1 = B1-A1
ba2 = B2-A2
t   = (ba1 * ca1 + ba2 * ca2) / (ba1 * ba1 + ba2 * ba2) 


D1 = ba1 * t + A1
D2 = ba2 * t + A2
```

Where `C1` and `C2` are the coordinates of `C`,
 `A1` and `A2` are the coordinates of `A`, ect.