# How to check if a point C(x3,y3) is falling between the straight line formed by two points A(x1,y1) & B(x2,y2)

Tags: geometry, line

I have two points A(x1,y1) & B(x2,y2) and I need to check if point c(x3,y3) falls on the straight line formed by point A & B.

A------C--------------------B  then yes C is between A & B

A---------------------------B
C
in second case C isn't between A & B.

Comment: I reverted your edit because it changes the problem drastically. You can make another question or use clue from my comment

Comment: okay. thanks.Ill go through the link that you've shared.

Answer (score 0):

Using complex numbers, we define a similarity transformation that maps A to 0 and B to 1:

```
W = (Z - Za) / (Zb - Za)
```

Then `Wc = (Zc - Za) / (Zb - Za)` is a complex number that should have a zero or tiny imaginary value, and a real value between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

Make two vectors

```
cax = x1 - x3
cay = y1 - y3

cbx = x2 - x3
cby = y2 - y3
```

and check that angle between them is `Pi`:

Calculate dot and cross product of these vectors

```
dot = cax * cbx + cay * cby
cross = cax * cby - cay * cbx
```

Point C lies on segment AB if `cross` is zero and `dot` is negative

```
dot < 0
abs(cross) < eps
```

where `eps` is small value like 1e-6 to compensate floating point calculation errors.

Comment: thanks, got it! I wanted to know how are the dot & cross products are gonna be affected if the point C falls on a line parallel to the one formed through point A & B. Actually point A & B both are representing coordinates of a road and I need to check if point C also falls on the same road or not. I don't have any other info available about the road. Point A & B are mine (as in from my database) but point C is coming from a third party so C won't always fall exactly on the straight line between A&B.

Comment: You can calculate distance from C to AB line as length of projection of C onto AB [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23772990/find-point-with-vector-projection/23773980#23773980) |CD| = |AC x AB|/|AB|

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure that all three point are aligned, you can use the dot product between vectors AC and AB, and the dot product between vectors BA and BC.

Reminder: Vector AB = (xB - xA, yB - yA)
Reminder: dot(AB, AC) = xAB*xAC + yAB*yAC

if dot(AB, AC) > 0, then it means C is in direction of B from A
if dot(BA, BC) > 0, then it means C is in direction of A from B
if both conditions above are satisfied, it means C is between A and B

Comment: Sadly, point C isn't always in alignment with A & B.

Comment: You can detect this using the dot product formula : dot(AB, AC) = length(AB) * length(AC) * cosinus(angle(AB,AC))