# How to detect collision of a circle on a polyline (line with multiple angles)?

Tags: algorithm, math, line, collision-detection

Lets assume we have a zig zag line or something with multiple angles. How exactly do you catch if a point is touching the line? For example, lets assume I have a scenario like this: [image]]

Comment: Shouldn't it be possble to simply check every segment for a collision with the circle? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073336/circle-line-segment-collision-detection-algorithm

Comment: @Marco13 you mean by searching for the nearest segment?

Comment: If you find the slope of the line and the slope of tangent line overlaps, you know they collide.

Comment: @Grendizer indeed but just from point A to B. That means I would have to loop through the lines segments and do the same check for each one?

Comment: I gotta think on how to minimize the number of steps to find the solution..

Comment: @Grendizer so then a function that does the typical check. I figure out the equation of a perpendicular line to the target line. Then I see where they intersect (intersection point). At last I check if target point and intersection point delta are near 0. If yes then there is a collision. Then I use this function in a loop. The loop gets all the lines that make up the polyline.

Comment: That sounds good :)

Comment: Is the motion of the circle linear?

Comment: @Grendizer the circle is actually the mouse coordinates and the line is an svg path. So I think yes.

Comment: If you just want to check **if** the circle touches one of the line segments (and not *where* it touches it), then you can just do `foreach (segment) if (circle.center.distanceTo(segment) < circle.radius) return true;`.

Answer (score 2):

The following python code works for me to compute the shortest distance from a point to a sequence of line segments:

```
from math import sqrt

def point_distance_to_line_segment((x,y),(lx1, ly1),(lx2, ly2)):
    line_length = sqrt((lx1-lx2)**2+(ly1-ly2)**2)
    dot_product = (x-lx1)*(lx2-lx1)+(y-ly1)*(ly2-ly1)

    proj_line = dot_product/line_length

    if proj_line < 0:
        # close to (x1,y1)
        return sqrt((x-lx1)**2+(y-ly1)**2)
    elif proj_line > line_length:
        # close to (x2,y2)
        return sqrt((x-lx2)**2+(y-ly2)**2)
    else:
        # in the middle
        cross_product = abs((x-lx1)*(ly2-ly1)-(y-ly1)*(lx2-lx1))
        return cross_product/line_length


line_pts = [(-1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (2,0)]
test_p = (-1, 0)

print min([point_distance_to_line_segment(test_p,lp1,lp2) 
           for (lp1,lp2) in zip(line_pts[0::2], line_pts[1::2])])
```

Not sure if there is a way to avoid iterating through all segments. Then you can simply compare this shortest distance to your circle radius.