# How to add collision in SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

I am working on creating pong but I have been having trouble with Collision.How can I add a pixel accurate Collision? I've created a collision when only using a main file but I can't figure it out when using header files.Can someone write out the code for Collision and add to a Collision.h and Collision.cpp for easy storage and modification.

main.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
#include "Paddle.h"
#include "Ball.h"
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode::getDesktopMode(), "Pong", 
    sf::Style::Close| sf::Style::Resize| sf::Style::Titlebar);
    Paddle paddle1;
    Paddle paddle2;
    Ball ball;
    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event evnt;
        while (window.pollEvent(evnt))
        {
            switch (evnt.type)
            {  
            case sf::Event::Closed:
                window.close();
                break;
            }
        }
        paddle1.Update();
        paddle2.Update();
        ball.Update(ballDirectionX,ballDirectionY);
        window.clear();
        paddle1.Draw(window);
        paddle2.Draw(window);
        ball.Draw(window);
        window.display();
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Paddle.h

```
#pragma once
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
class Paddle
{
public:
    Paddle();
    ~Paddle();
    void Draw(sf::RenderWindow& window);
    void Update();
    sf::RectangleShape paddle1;
    sf::RectangleShape paddle2;
private:
};
```

Paddle.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Paddle.h"
Paddle::Paddle()
{
    paddle1.setSize(sf::Vector2f(20.0f, 120.0f));
    paddle1.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
    paddle2.setSize(sf::Vector2f(20.0f, 120.0f));
    paddle2.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);
    paddle2.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(1900.0f, 0.0f));
}
Paddle::~Paddle()
{
} 
void Paddle::Draw(sf::RenderWindow& window)
{
    window.draw(paddle1);
    window.draw(paddle2);
}
void Paddle::Update()
{
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::W)) {
        paddle1.move(sf::Vector2f(0, -3));
    }
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::S)) {
        paddle1.move(sf::Vector2f(0, 3));
    }
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up)) {
        paddle2.move(sf::Vector2f(0, -3));
    }
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down)) {
        paddle2.move(sf::Vector2f(0, 3));
    }
}
```

Ball.h

```
#pragma once
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
class Ball
{
public:
     Ball();
     ~Ball();
     void Draw(sf::RenderWindow& window);
     void Update() {
     }
     sf::CircleShape ball;
private:    

};
```

Ball.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Ball.h"
Ball::Ball()
{
    ball.setRadius(20);
    ball.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(400, 540));
}
Ball::~Ball()
{
}
void Ball::Draw(sf::RenderWindow & window)
{
window.draw(ball);
}
void Ball::Update()
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Pong is a very simple game, I suggest you to create an intersect function with a `sf::CircleShape` and a `sf::RectangleShape` as arguments, because that's how you are representing your ball and paddles respectively.

I suggest you the following implementation, but there are [better ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073336/circle-line-segment-collision-detection-algorithm):

```
bool intersects(const sf::CircleShape &c, const sf::RectangleShape &r){
    sf::FloatRect fr = r.getGlobalBounds();
    sf::Vector2f topLeft(fr.left, fr.top);
    sf::Vector2f topRight(fr.left + fr.width, fr.top);
    sf::Vector2f botLeft(fr.left, fr.top + fr.height);
    sf::Vector2f botRight(fr.left + fr.width, fr.top + fr.height);

    return contains(c, topLeft) || 
        contains(c, topRight) || 
        contains(c, botLeft) || 
        contains(c, botRight);
}
```

This is easy, simply check if each corner of the rectangle is inside of the circle, if **none** of them is contained, that circle and that rectangle **don't intersect**.

If any of the corners are contained into the circle, they intersects.

The `contains()` function quite simple in fact:

```
bool contains(const sf::CircleShape &c, const sf::Vector2f &p){
    sf::Vector2f center = c.getPosition();
    float a = (p.x - center.x);
    float b = (p.y - center.y);
    a *= a;
    b *= b;
    float r = c.getRadius() * c.getRadius();

    return (( a + b ) < r);
}
```

Is based in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481144/equation-for-testing-if-a-point-is-inside-a-circle) question, but I've separated it in each step for better comprehension.

---

**EDIT**

Note that this method only works if rectangles are in a vertical/horizontal orientation, this is, no rotations.

Comment: If the ball reaches the center of the bat, it will intersect without hitting any corner.

Comment: In that case, it won't be difficult to change the method for something like [this line-circle intersection algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073336/circle-line-segment-collision-detection-algorithm) with the advantage of detecting with rotated rectangles too

Comment: If you add a `getShape()` method in both `Ball` and `Paddle` classes, you could write `intersects` and `contains` directly above `main`

Comment: Can you write it out for me in how i have my code set up, not just what to but add it to make it easier for me?