# capsule - ray (line segment) intersection, 2D

Tags: algorithm, math, collision-detection

i am programming a C++ collision detection in my game and am trying to come up with an algorithm:
I have a capsule defined with two center points (C1, C2), length and a radius. Then i have a ray defined with two points (R1, R2). I already know that they are intersecting. I just need to find inner part of ray that is contained in capsule (H1-H2). Thanks in advance for all the help.

[image]

Comment: This attitude is exactly why so many knowledgable engineers I know are leaving SO. The second bullet in the help on "What topics can I ask" is "a software algorithm." This is _clearly_ a question of that sort. It's absolutely related to programming. @Someprogrammerdude

Answer (score 3):

First let's take a look at a diagram for reference:

[image]

The procedure for calculating `H1` and `H2` is as follows:

1. Compute the intersection, if any, between the ray `R` and the line
   segment `P1P2`. We're only interested in intersections that lie
   within the interior of `P1P2`. Similarly for `P3P4`. The points `P1` to `P4` can be calculated easily from the circle centers, `C1` and `C2`, and some vector math. E.g. `P1 = C1 + r*nC`, where `nC` is the normal (CCW) of the unit vector from `C1` to `C2`. This
   [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/565282/6438819) on SO provides the necessary math to determine if an
   intersection exists between two line segments and, if so, calculate the parameter `h`, such
   that `H=R1+h(R2-R1)`, where `H` is an intersection point. This step can produce 0, 1,    or 2 valid `h` values, depending on whether the ray intersects neither, one, or both of `P1P2`, `P3P4`.
2. Compute the intersection points, if any, between the ray and each of the 2
   circles. Again, an SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1084899/6438819) provides the necessary math for
   ray to circle intersection. Each circle can produce 0, 1, or 2
   intersections, again represented parametrically.
3. If no valid `h` values were generated from steps 1 & 2 then the ray does not intersect the capsule. Otherwise, calculate `hMin` and `hMax`, the min and max parameter values of all valid
   intersections identified in steps 1 & 2. Note that it's possible that `hMin==hMax`, in the case where the ray is tangent to one of the circles and does not intersect `P1P2` or `P3P4`. The required intersection point(s) can now be calculated as `H1=R1+hMin(R2-R1)` and `H2=R1+hMax(R2-R1)`.

I'm afraid my language of choice is Java rather than C++, but hopefully you'll find the code ([IDEOne](https://ideone.com/ThgLbv)) I put together helpful as a reference. Please be aware that no effort was put it to handle robustness issues resulting from the rounding of `double` values during calculations.