# determining algorithm for calculating a point intersecting a circle where the segment crosses from inside to the outside of the circle

Tags: algorithm, geometry, intersect

I have a line segment between points A and B.  A is inside a circle with a center at 0,0 with a radius of R.  I am stumped trying to come up with an efficient way to calculate the intersection of line segment AB with this circle.

Comment: The equation of a circle is `x^2 + y^2 = r^2`. The equation of a line is `y = mx + b`. So `x^2 + (mx + b)^2 = r^2`.

Comment: So that would be x^2 +m^2x^2 + 2mx + 2b + b^2 - r^2 = 0 simplified a bit becomes

Comment: So that would be x^2 +m^2x^2 + 2mx + 2b + b^2 - r^2 = 0 simplified a bit becomes (m^2+1)x^2+2mx+(2b+b^2-r^2) = 0 which one uses the quadratic equation to solve (where m = (A,x - B.x)/(A.y-B.y), and b is gotten from A.y = mA,x + b, solving for b, b = A,y - mA.x.  Then you just have to determine which of the two resultant answers give a point that is between A and B.  Thanks you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Circle line-segment collision detection algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073336/circle-line-segment-collision-detection-algorithm)

Comment: I don't think so, it's a more limited case in requirements.  Collision detection is not an issue at all and I had thought perhaps the answer would in total be simplifiable in some way beyond my ability to determine.  Also, my summary above has errors, such as x and y being on the wrong parts of the calculation in the equation for m.

Answer (score 0):

This is a mere second degree equation resolution

Line is  y=A.x +B  , where A and B are constants
Circle is y^2=R^2 - x^2   , where R is the radius, and circle center is 0,0

so (A.x+B)^2=R^2-x^2 => A^2.x^2 +2.A.x.B +B^2 =R^2 -x^2  =>
(A^2+1).x^2 + 2.A.B.x +B^2-R^2 =0

The algorithm is :

let P=A^2+1 , G=2.A.B , H=B^2-R^2
The equation is : P.x^2 + G.x + H=0

that gives 3 cases depending on delta
delta=G^2-4*P*H

If delta<0 => no intersections
if delta=0 => intersect in 1 point : x=-G/2*P  and y=Ax+B
if delta>0 => intersect in 2 points : x1=(-G-sqrt(delta))/(2*P) , y1=Ax1+B  and x2=(-G+sqrt(delta))/(2*P) ,y2=Ax2+B    (where sqrt is the square root)

Comment: Collision detection is not needed, as the line segment is guaranteed to intersect the circle (one endpoint will be inside or on the edge of the circle, the other will be outside of the circle).  Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

> Then you just have to determine which of the two resultant answers give a point that is between A and B.

Let's call two resultants `I1` and `I2`. To determine which one is the answer, you need to check directions of `A->I1` and `A->I2` vectors against `A->B`, where `A` is the point that is located inside the circle:

```
% line: y = mx + b
m = (yB - yA) / (xB - xA);
b = yA - m * xA;

% circle: x^2 + y^2 = r^2
% intersection: x^2 + (mx + b)^2 = r^2
% ...           x^2 + m^2x^2 + b^2 + 2mbx - r^2 = 0
% ...           (1 + m^2)x^2 + 2mbx + (b^2 - r^2) = 0

A = 1 + m^2;
B = 2 * m * b;
C = b^2 - r^2;
sqrtD = sqrt(B^2 - 4*A*C);

xI = (-B+sqrtD) / (2*A);
yI = m * xI + b;

if (abs(atan2(yB - yA, xB - xA)-atan2(yI - yA, xI - xA)) > 1e-5)
    xI = (-B-sqrtD) / (2*A);
    yI = m * xI + b;
end
```

**Remark #1:** I didn't check the delta for being negative, since you said one point is inside the circle and the other is outside of it.

**Remark #2:** You need to cover the special case where `A == B`.

**Remark #3:** You need to cover the special case where `xA == xB`.

**Remark #4:** You can pick the correct answer with much less cost than finding the slope of two vectors, calculating the absolute variance between them and comparing the result with an epsilon! :)

Comment: I think the usage of atan can be avoided by simply comparing the x and y coordinates of the intercept point to the end points, if both x and y are between the x and y values of the end points then that's the correct answer, otherwise it's the other intersection.

Comment: That's it @Mudcrush!